# SPM showing duplicate target name fatalError

Tags: ios, swift, swift-package-manager, lib

I'm facing a problem with my lib using SPM.

I've developed it using a target into the project to test and works fine.
After finish I've added the lib using SPM into a final project using the branch develop and I was able to integrate lib and project.

When I saw that is all right, I made a tag from my lib and import into project using Up To Next Major (tag)

And using this way I'm getting this error:
[image]

I've checked all the code, compare Package.swift with other projects, change the name, change de folder and nothing.

Here my Package.swift

```
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "GloboUI",
    platforms: [
        .iOS(.v12)
    ],
    products: [
        // Products define the executables and libraries a package produces, and make them visible to other packages.
        .library(
            name: "GloboUI", targets: ["GloboUI"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
        .package(url: "https://github.com/rechsteiner/Parchment", exact: "3.1.0"),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher.git", from: "7.0.0"),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-ios.git", from: "4.0.0"),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/googleads/swift-package-manager-google-mobile-ads.git", from: "9.0.0")
    ],
    targets: [
        // Targets are the basic building blocks of a package. A target can define a module or a test suite.
        // Targets can depend on other targets in this package, and on products in packages this package depends on.
        .target(
            name: "GloboUI",
            dependencies: [
                .product(name: "GoogleMobileAds", package: "swift-package-manager-google-mobile-ads"),
                .product(name: "Parchment", package: "Parchment"),
                .product(name: "Kingfisher", package: "Kingfisher"),
                .product(name: "Lottie", package: "lottie-ios")
            ],
            path: "Sources/GloboUI"
        )
    ]
)
```

I tried remove and change this path in target, change the target names...a lot of try

Here my folder structure of the lib

[image]

I've tried remove package.resolved form the main project, clean derivate data, cache, everything.

But I'm not know what is happening.

Anyone has a clue about this issue?

Regards

Comment: have you tackled this problem?

Comment: @AlexKraev not yet